# Why equate an identity matrix to a transformation matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

In opencv and C++, if I have previously found a transformation matrix between 2 images, why do I need to do this

```
Mat affineTransform=getAffineTransform(coordinates_1.data(),coordinates_2.data()) ;
Mat perspectiveTransform=Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64FC1);
for(unsigned int y=0; y<2; ++y){
    for(unsigned int x=0; x<3; ++x){
        perspectiveTransform.at<double>(y,x) = affineTransform.at<double>(y,x);
    }
```

instead of applying the transformation matrix to an image directly. I understand the meaning of Mat::eye() but why go through all this?

Note: **originalTranformationMatrix** is a Mat object and the found transformation matrix is a 3 x 3 matrix

Comment: this is pretty unclear. could you replace your pseudocode with something real ?

Comment: yes I have replaced the pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affine transform has following form:

```
(a, b, c)
(d, e, f)
```

It transform point (x,y) in following way:

```
x_new = a*x + b*y + c;
y_new = d*x + e*y + f;
```

Perspective transform has following form:

```
(a, b, c)
(d, e, f)
(g, h, 1)
```

It transform point (x,y) in following way:

```
z = g*x + h*y + 1;
x_new = (a*x + b*y + c)/z;
y_new = (d*x + e*y + f)/z;
```

That means that if you want to define perspective transform that does only affine transformation, it should be:

```
(a, b, c)
(d, e, f)
(0, 0, 1)
```

And this is exactly what your code does. First it creates matrix:

```
(1, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
```

And than replaces first two rows with rows of affine transformation. By the way, it can be done in cleaner way without loops:

```
perspectiveTransform(Rect(0,0,3,2)) = affineTransform.clone();
```